# Xcode archive, Why did EnterPrise ipa'size less than AppStore's?

Tags: xcode, app-store, ipa, enterprise, iphone-developer-program

The same project.I use the different BundleID archive IPA file.

Enterprise : 29Mb
App Store  : 66Mb

Why would happen that？Does different archive due to the ipa size different?I didn't use bitcode, or other way to strip code.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `ipa` you submit to AppStore is containing all the possible size of assets optimized to each device. So the size you build the `ipa` is bigger and not meaning anything because it is not reflecting the actual size.

If you want to know about the size of the app downloading from AppStore, you can check it after you submit to `itunesonnect`. That will be the real size.

> itunesconnect (App Store Connect) > Your App > Activity > All Builds > Your Build > General Information > Compressed File Size > App Store File Sizes

[image]

Comment: Actually, I had upload the ipa on TestFilght.It's download size is 66Mb, just like the picture you show. The Enterprise's ipa file upload on my server. It only take 29.6Mb.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. Check out the ipa, there's Symbols files in it. When you archive app, don't choose include symbols. It makes the ipa file small.
[image]

**With out symbols, my ipa file size is 31Mb, upload to iTunesConnect, it's size is 48.9Mb.** I guess it's because iTunesConnect decompresses it and recompresses it. Anyone has ideas ? Is it true?
[image]